# How can I position elements relative to a centered div?

Tags: html, css, centering

I want to center two buttons that are on the same line, and then I want to position a selector on the same line, to the right of the two centered buttons. How can I do it? In other words, how can I position an element relative to a centered div?

EDIT: I want the end result to look something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoDav.png

Comment: Hey, could you provide a small sketch or something to understand what it is you want to accomplish? Also, consider checking out this resource: http://howtocenterincss.com

Comment: Sure! I edited the main post to include it. Thank you for the resource! It doesn't help with my current problem, but it's good to know for the future that it exists.

Comment: `position: absolute` for last element

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox does the job quite well!

```css
.wrapper {  
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  text-align:center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height:40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  
}

.m {
  width: 100%;
}
.m button {
  width: 100px;
}
.r {   
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="m">
    <button>a</button>  
    <button>b</button>
  </div>
  <div class="r">Section C</div>
</div>
```